# Is there any way to give an offset to raycaster three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to make a pool game in three.js. I have a helper ruler that shows the direction of hit. It's an ArrowHelper that is located in y=0 same as my raycaster to detect borders. But I also need it to detect a ball which center is upper than y=0. It's on y = 0.35. And I am wondering how to displace my raycaster upper in scene, so it can also detect my ball.
Is there any way to displace my raycaster in y?

Comment: Have you considered to just change the `origin` property of the raycaster's internal ray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the origin and direction of your raycaster in 3D space, you can simply use [`raycaster.set()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.set) because it lets you specify both attributes, just make sure your direction is [always normalized](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.normalize) (total magnitude = 1):

```
let origin = new THREE.Vector3(x1, y1, z1);
origin.y += 0.35;
let direction = new THREE.Vector3(x2, y2, z2);
raycaster.set(origin, direction.normalize());
```